# How can I change the color and the size of the dots in ngx-owl-carosel-Angular?

Tags: angular, owl-carousel

How can I change the color and the size of the dots in the ngx-owl-carousel-o in Angular? I have tried everything and it is not working. How can I overwrite the basic owl-carousel styles?

```js
customOptions: OwlOptions = {
    loop: true,
    mouseDrag: true,
    touchDrag: true,
    pullDrag: true,
    dots: true,
    navSpeed: 700,
    navText: ['', ''],
    items: 1,
    nav: false
  }
```

```css
.owl-theme .owl-dots {
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot {
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
}
.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot span {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 5px 7px;
  background:yellow;
  display: block;
  
}
.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot.active span,
.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot:hover span {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<owl-carousel-o [options]="carouselOptions">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let slide of slides">
    <ng-template carouselSlide>
      <img [src]="slide.img">
    </ng-template>
  </ng-container>
</owl-carousel-o>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot span {
  background: yellow !important;
}

.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot.active span,
.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot:hover span {
  background: red !important;
}
```

*In CSS, the "!important" rule makes a property more important than usual. When you use it, it overrides any previous styling for that property on that element.*

Or as @Eliseo mentioned, simply use a more specific CSS:

Add class="custom-owl"

```html
<owl-carousel-o
 class="custom-owl"
 [options]="carouselOptions">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let slide of slides">
    <ng-template carouselSlide>
      <img [src]="slide.img">
    </ng-template>
  </ng-container>
</owl-carousel-o>
```

```scss
.custom-owl {
  .owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot span {
    background: yellow !important;
  }

  .owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot.active span,
  .owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot:hover span {
    background: red !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try avoid use `!important`, use a "more specify" .css, an [interesting link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) about it

Comment: It does not work with important. I really do not what to do.

Comment: check if your CSS is really loaded